# How do I add days to the current date field to be able to compare range of dates

Tags: mongodb

I need to do the following MySql approach in MongoDB:

```
SELECT * FROM table T WHERE DATE_ADD(T.createdAt, INTERVAL 2 DAY) > someDate;
```

I was thinking on aggregations, expressions, Etc., but I couldn't find a way to approach this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it’s no needed the sample document because my question is about the translation of that MySQL query into a Mongodb query. Basically, find the documents where the field `createdAt + days` is greater than `somedate`.

Comment: if you don't want to do this in query, you can minus 2 days from `someDate` in your client side. so just need to match only greater than condition in query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `$add` here:

```
db.yourCollection.find({
    "createdAt": { $gt: { $add: [ "$someDate", -1000 * 3600 * 24 * 3 ] } }
});
```

The above assumes that both fields `createdAt` and `someDate` are ISO timestamps.  Note that I have actually rephrased your query as follows, so that `createdAt` appears by itself on the LHS of the inequality:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE createdAt > someDate - INTERVAL 2 DAY;
```

Comment: Adding a negative value could be confusing (although it should be no problem for a SW developer). You can also use `$subtract()`

Answer (score 0):

When you have to work with date/time values then I recommend the [moment.j](https://momentjs.com/docs/)s library. Would be this one:

```
db.collection.find({
   createdAt: { $gte: { moment().subtract(2, 'days').toDate() } } 
})
```

Comment: Would this also work from the Mongo shell?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, if you run `load("<folder>\moment.js")` before.

Comment: Thanks for taking a _moment_ to reply to my comment; just learned something new ^ ^.